# Increase the priority in queue

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, build-process, tfsbuild

Using TFS Build Server as contionuous integration system, I would like to know if it is possible to set some build definitions as High Priotity Builds.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly, but there is an approach I've used to accomplish a similar thing.  If you setup multiple build agents (on one build server, or multiple servers), you can use Build Agent Tags.

Lets say you have 4 build agents.  What you can do is tag 3 of them with a tag like "LowPriority", and leave the 4th agent with no tags.

Then in your low priority build definitions tell them to only run on build agents with the LowPriority tag, set the high priority build def's to run on any build agent.

This effectively reserves a build agent to be used only for high priority builds, which will allow them to "jump the queue".

[image]

Comment: This is a good aproach but the problem is that I cannot use more than one  build agent.

Comment: Then no, there is no way to specify a specific build def as higher priority if you only have one agent.